# I'm trying to add env var to django secret_key on github action but showing error

Tags: django, github-actions

```yaml
name: MoneyTracker Test

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - master

    pull_request:
        branches:
            - master

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2
            - name: Set up python 3.7
              uses: actions/setup-python@v2
              with:
                python-version: 3.7
            - name: Install dependency
              run: |
                  python -m pip install --upgrade pip
                  pip install -r requirements.txt
            - name: Lint with flake8
              run: |
                  pip install flake8
                  flake8
            - name: Coverage report
              env:
                  secret_key: ${{secrets.SECRET_KEY}}
                  debug: ${{secrets.DEBUG}}
                  db: ${{secrets.DB}}
              run: |
                  pip install coverage
                  coverage run MoneyTracker/manage.py test
                  coverage report
            - name: Django testing
              run: |
                  python3 MoneyTracker/manage.py test MoneyTracker
```

Project link is in [here](https://github.com/coderj001/MoneyTracker).
How should I add secret key to my project on GitHub action?
Environment variables are case-sensitive. Commands run in actions or steps can create, read, and modify environment variables. To set custom environment variables, you need to specify the variables in the workflow file. You can define environment variables for a step, job, or entire workflow using the jobs.

Comment: What is the issue? Did you try to add a secret key to your project following these instructions? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository

Answer (score 5):

**1. (Recommended way for Secrets)** The preferred and secure way is to add the Secret env variables in your GitHub repo settings (See this [Link] for more info. Then you can use those variables with the below syntax in your `actions/django.yml` file.

```
env:
  SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}
```

See below image or this [Link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository)

[Add Secrets in Github Repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dufJ.png)

**1. (Not recommended for Secrets)** You can set the env variables using the below syntax, or you can follow [Official Docs Here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#about-environment-variables). But if your repo is public then this method will still expose your SECRET_KEY so I wouldn't recommend this for secrets. However, this method can be used if you want to set env variables like PATH.

```
env:
  SECRET_KEY: your_django_secret_key
```